# How to retrieve an array with value within another array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve the array that has value within another array using filter method. So for instance, from this

```
[[], [{name:"shop", price: 48}],[]]
```

to this

```
[{name:"shop", price: 48}]
```

From console.log below I get `{name:"shop", price: 48}`, but when I return `v`, I get whole thing back--> `[[], [{name:"shop", price: 48}],[]]`

What am I missing?

```js
const a = [[], [{name:"shop", price: 48}],[]]

const output = a.map((value) => {
  return value.filter((v) =>{
    console.log(v)
    return v
  })
})
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Your map function does nothing except cloning your initial array, so what do you expect?

Comment: What if several arrays are non-empty, what do you you expect in those cases?

Comment: If you want to filter out empty arrays, then apply such filter.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```js
const a = [[], [{name:"shop", price: 48}],[]]

const [ output ] = a.filter(v => v.length); // will filter out empty arrays

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution of joining subarrays into one array:

```
const a = [[], [{name:"shop", price: 12}], [{name:"shop", price: 34}]];

let res = [];
a.forEach((aItem) => res = res.concat(aItem));

console.log(res);
```

Output

```
[ { name: 'shop', price: 12 }, { name: 'shop', price: 34 } ]
```